# Unit Testing How can I mock `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params);` call?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

How can I mock `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params);` call where it returns an instance of `DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>`?

I have gone through the following article and created my own context.

[Entity Framework Testing with Your Own Test Doubles (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314431(v=vs.113).aspx)

In the product code, there is a call to `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, params);` method and the code is consuming `ToListAsync` method of `DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>`.

I am stuck here to mock this call.

Comment: Avoid having to mock implementation concerns. There could be an underlying design issue. It means that your code is tight coupled to implementation concerns. try depending on abstraction. Show a [mcve] of the desired behavior and see if an answer on how to achieve it via abstractions can be done.